# How to install Aurora (Firefox) on Debian?

Tags: debian, firefox, iceweasel

How to install the latest Firefox build (called Aurora) on Debian unstable? Are there any packages or repositories?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To install the latest build of Firefox (Aurora), or one of the release, beta, extended support release (ESR) versions, use instructions from http://mozilla.debian.net. Basically you choose your distribution (stable, testing, unstable), choose Firefox, choose the version, then add a string in `/etc/apt/sources.list`, then update the packages list. Then run

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -t experimental firefox
```

You would also possibly need to install package `pkg-mozilla-archive-keyring` for APT not to complain about untrusted sources.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to enter http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/aurora/ and simply download, unpack and run Aurora from there. This will give you the absolutely latest version, however it is for Firefox and not for the Iceweasel fork, and it won't use a repo (or Debian package).